# Slick 3.1 Polymorphic Keys and Type Conversions

Tags: scala, shapes, slick, slick-3.0

I am trying to create a Slick query equivalent to `select ... where owner_id in (select ...)`. The problem is that `owner_id` is a polymorphic key and that our table id's are typed.

```
class Id[+M](val value: Long) extends MappedTo[Long]
```

I'd like to write a query like this:

```
val Apples: Query[ApplesTable, Apple, Seq] = ...
val Farmers: Query[FarmersTable, Farmer, Seq] = ...

Apples.filter(apple =>
  apple.ownerType === "FARMER" &&
  apple.ownerId.in(Farmers.map(_.id))
)
```

This fails because the owner is defined as `val ownerId = column[Option[Long]](...)`, so `apple.ownerId.in` expects a query with entity type of `Long`, whereas `Farmers.map(_.id)` returns entities of type `Id[Farmer]`.

Is there a way to turn a query of type `Query[FarmersTable, Id[Farmer], Seq]` to a query of type `Query[FarmersTable, Long, Seq]`?

Given the signature of `Query.map` method (below), I believe that the solution lies in constructing a correct `Shape` instance. However, I could not find a proper factory.

```
/** Build a new query by applying a function to all elements of this query. */
def map[F, G, T](f: E => F)(implicit shape: Shape[_ <: FlatShapeLevel, F, T, G]): Query[G, T, C] =
  flatMap(v => Query[F, T, G](f(v)))
```

**Update:**
`ownerId` is typed as `Option[Long]` because it is nullable and we want to join it with different models depending on `ownerType` (e.g. `case class Farmer(id: Id[Farmer], ...)` or `case class HungryJerry(id: Id[HungryJerry], ...)`.

Comment: what's the point of using `MappedTo` and *not* defining the column as the corresponding value class? In other words, why is your owner_id not an `Id`? If you want you can define an `Id` trait with an abstract member; then your UserId, PlayerId, etc. value classes extend the trait providing the implementation type of Long, Int, ...

Comment: We use ```Long``` for ```ownerId``` because it's a polymorphic key. In other words, we would like to map it to instances of ```Id[Farmer]``` or ```Id[HungryJerry]``` at runtime.

Comment: You don't even use `+M` in your Id value class; in what is it polymorphic? Looks like its fixed to `Long` unless your real world code is different. Rather than `Id[Farmer]` you could do `trait Id[T] extends Any with MappedTo[T]` and then `case class FarmerId(value: Long) extends AnyVal with Id[Long]`. That way you have `typed` values across the board.

Comment: A polymorphic key is a key in the database which points conditionally to rows in different tables. In this case, ```apples.owner_id``` can point to ```farmers.id``` or to an id in another table, depending on the corresponding value of ```apples.owner_type```. In other words, I am not trying to map ```Id``` objects to different Slick primitive types (Int, Long), but instead to map the same column (```apples.owner_id```) to different types (```Id[Farmer]```, ```Id[Merchant]```, etc.). If you think that covariant id's would help with this, please elaborate, as I fail to see how, thus far.

Comment: Just read up on polymorphic keys...interesting design choice, personally I'd go with multiple foreign keys or find some other way to guarantee consistency at database level. Anyway, since you're using `ownerType` (I'd make that an Enum or ADT, btw) as a conditional guard for `apple.ownerId.in(Farmers.map(_.id))`, why not just go with `case class OwnerId(value: Long) extends MappedTo[Long]`? I mean, it's all the same soup with polymorphic keys; at least with an OwnerId value class you can work with strong types, and it works out of the box with Slick, no need for extra hacks.

Comment: We're designing a framework for use in multiple projects, so code reusability is high priority. Therefore, I shy away from defining multiple models with ids of type ```OwnerId``` (for example, what if ```Farmer``` participates in another polymorphic relationship, say "employer of"? We'd need a type like ```OwnerIdOrEmployeeId``` serving as the id of farmers, merchants, and waiters). I have considered using ```column[Id[Nothing]]``` in the table definition, but couldn't get ```apple.ownerId.in(Farmers.map(_.id))``` to work with that either.

Comment: Honestly, the easiest thing to do is just scrap trying to type the relations and go with plain `Long`s everywhere. That's more reflective of underlying database schema where polymorphic keys sacrifice fkey constraints (i.e. the criteria by which a column can be viewed as unique at application level) in exchange for flexibility in sql relations. Curious why join tables wouldn't provide same flexibility as polymorphic keys (sure, more boilerplate, but easily `typed` with Slick)

Comment: Unfortunately, the schema is a given, and the polymorphic keys are not going away any time soon, so it looks like we'll have to drop this idea with typed id's. Still, I find it surprising that there is no easy way in Slick to map between related types at the query level (e.g. from ```Query[..., Int, Seq]``` to ```Query[..., Long, Seq]```).